# show popup as Dropdown when I click specific button

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, drop-down-menu, popup

```
val xoffset = 25
        val yoffset = 0
        binding.filterButton.setOnClickListener{
            popup.showAsDropDown(binding.filterButton,xoffset,yoffset)
        }
```

yoffset works properly if I give any value it will work but xoffset not work

i want show popup as a dropdown button bottom left side.

Answer (score 0):

Set **GravityFlags** parameters as bottom-left

popup.showDropDown(
view,
int ,
int ,
**gravity**
)

Answer (score -1):

To show a popup as a dropdown from the bottom left side of a button, you need to set the `xoffset` value to a negative number to move the popup to the left side of the button. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```kotlin
val xoffset = -25 // Use a negative value to move the popup to the left side
val yoffset = 0
binding.filterButton.setOnClickListener {
    popup.showAsDropDown(binding.filterButton, xoffset, yoffset)
}
```

I haven't tried the code, let me know if it works.

Comment: bro it's not work I already tried this